# Modal doesn't hide when outside click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I've create a modal it works fine but when click outside it doesn't hide anymore. how can i do this? please help me anyone. thanks

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myBtn" class=" postsubmit-btn">Post</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content ">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the close button?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code to close the modal on click outside the modal.

There is error in the span tag because span not available in your html code.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");



// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}



// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Post</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">   
      <h2>Modal</h2>   
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use stopPropagation() method to open and close model,

please have a look below updated code, hope this will help/resolved your issues.

```html
<button type="button" id="myBtn" class=" postsubmit-btn">Post</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content ">
  </div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<style>
.modal{width:300px; height:300px; background:#f5f5f5; display:none;}
.close{float:right}
</style>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target != modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.contains(event.target)` to check if the click was on the element or one of its children. You can also use `event.target!="myBtn"` to make sure clicking on the button opens the modal.

```css
.modal{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myBtn" class=" postsubmit-btn">Post</button><button class="close">&times;</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-content">
  MODAL
  </div>
</div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.id!="myBtn"&&!modal.contains(event.target)) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```